# How pass dynamic Table name to PHP codeigniter-base-model

Tags: php, rest

I am using PHP and jamierumbelow/codeigniter-base-model. 
I have tables as following

```
Table name: class_2014
Table name: class_2015
Table name: class_2016
```

All class_* tables are identical in structure basis, similar field names and other properties. Only difference is name and data.

I have a variable in PHP which holder YEAR value, for example $strYear = '2015' .

***How I can pass or build $_table parameter dynamically to "Model_*" base on whatever value variable strYear holds? , for example $strYear = '2015'***

My Model file is as following,

```
<?php
class Model_class extends MY_Model{
    protected $_table = 'class_2015'; //HOW TO PASS THIS DYNAMICALLY
    protected $primary_key = 'classId';
    protected $return_type = 'array';
}
```

My get function as following,

```
// GET CLASS
    function class_get(){
        $classId = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $this->load->model('Model_class');
        $strYear = '2015'
        if(!$classId) {
            $class = $this->Model_class->get_all();
        }else{
            $class = $this->Model_class->get_by(array('classId'=>$classId));
        }
        if(isset($class['classId'])){
            $this->response($class);
        }else{
            $this->response($class);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you just use one table with year column to identify the year? Redundant table structure imho.

Comment: Well I can do that what to advising but for some reason I am not taking that path. Is there any ways to achieve what I looking for?

Comment: I'm also looking for the same solution, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can add Construct to your model like this:

```
public function __construct($name)
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->_table = $name;
}
```

And when you call you model in the controller give the name as parameter like this:

```
 $MyModel = new MyModel($name)
```